# Possible to add a worker on-the-fly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When starting a TensorFlow server (`tf.distribute.Server`), you must pass a `ClusterSpec` which specifies all tasks/workers in the cluster.

Is it possible, after you started the server, to add further workers to it? How?

If not, why not?

(This is related to the question, [why does the server need to know at all about all the workers in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004631/why-does-a-tf-server-needs-to-know-about-all-other-tasks-workers-in-the-cluster)
Although it is not quite the same question.)

(This is also related to the question, [what operators are there for remote communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993679/what-operators-are-there-for-remote-communication) Currently I only know about this (official) [distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute) functionality, via a TF server with `ClusterSpec`.
Other inofficial solutions are e.g. [Tensorpack](https://tensorpack.readthedocs.io/) [TF ZMQ ops](https://github.com/tensorpack/zmq_ops), where you can communicate in whatever way you want (via ZeroMQ), and you also do not need to know the whole cluster beforehand / in advance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, I don't think it is possible to add further workers/tasks to a running server.

The [tf.distribute.Server class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.py#L148) uses the server class of [TensorFlow's low-level C API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc). This class provides an [UpdateServerDef method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc#L410), which probably could be used to modify the configuration of a running server, and consequently to change the workers/tasks.

However, this update method is not exposed via the [TensorFlow python binding](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ffb230a4b7c113e61b8dafdd3895c747833140a3/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_wrapper.cc#L992), so unless you are willing to modify and compile your own TensorFlow C core I don't think it is possible.